# Need Guidance to maintain NSTimer with each Tablview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

What Could Be Best Approach if i need to work with timer for each cell,

**Example:-** Each cell start with time countdown start with some value (assume 50) and it will decrease on each clock tick till zero, when it's value is zero we need to remove that cell with animation. and one every sec we should update that each cel counter value as timer for each cell will change. I really need help to achieve this workaround. you suggestion can make my implementation easy.

Workaround **(which i think good)** was to implement timer in NSManageObject with timer property(NSTimer) and use NSFetchedResultsController to listen datasource change to update tableview. But is this good way to maintain whole tableview with sections with this approach ?

**Thanks in advance for help.**

Comment: When do you intend to start the timer? At creation time of the cell, or when it is displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumbers`, where each NSNumber represents the remaining value.
Displaying these in a `UITableView` is then quite straight forward.

Then set up a repeating `NSTimer` that 'ticks' every second. On every tick iterate through the array and decrement the value.  If the value is 0, remove that element from the array and the corresponding row from the table (assuming `self.values` is your NSMutableArray of cell counts) -

```
-(void) handleTick {

  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  NSMutableArray *reloadRows=[NSMutableArray new];
  for (int i=0;i<self.values.count;i++) {
    NSNumber *number=self.values[i];
    NSInteger val=[number integerValue]-1;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    if (val > 0) {
        values[i]=NSNumber numberWithInteger:val];
        [reloadRows addObject:indexPath];
    }
    else {

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];   
        [self.values removeObjectAtIndex:i--];
    }
  }

  if (reloadRows.count > 0) {
      [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  }

  [self.tableView endUpdates];

  if (self.values.count == 0) {
      [self.timer invalidate];       // Stop the timer if there is no data left
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the most sensible way. It just feels like a bad idea to create a timer for every cell...

Comment: There is only a single timer in this solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I was talking about OP's workaround with multiple timers - seems like a bad idea. This one is a good answer.

Comment: The NSNumbers could also be part of the NSManagedObject to make the countdowns persistent.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't sure whether the OP wanted to persist the data or they were just using Core Data as a notification framework.  It would be a trivial change if that is what they wanted

Comment: Sound seems like its good solution let me try for that.. @Paulw11 you approach looks good single timer is enough to maintain tableview. it will efficient also with cpu process and memory management.

Comment: Scrolling performance is related to the complexity of the cell - so if the cell is just a text field or two I wouldn't expect any issues. Even if you were updating at tenths of a second rather than every second performance would still be ok

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you want to do. As the "Example" said, you can use one timer for all cells. Each cell has an initial value (maybe different), every sec, you count down the values, if a cell's value reaches zero, remove it from the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's a best code but try it

1)Make a subclass of your tableViewCell

2)Make cell properties int: counter; NSTimer *countdownTimer; UIViewController *parentController;

3)Write kind of -(void)startCountDown and -(void)countDown method in cell;

4)In startCountDown method call

```
 NSTimer *countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

5)In countDown method do counter -= counter and check if counter > 0. If it is call some method in parentController which will do what you want and reload tableview Data. Dont forget to invalidate timer.

6)In cellForRowAtIndexPath: set counter and parentController for your cell and call [cell startCountDown];

Comment: I'd recommend against using a timer per cell, since the ticks need to be called every second anyway, there is no reason to not have one single timer for everything. One per cell just begs for reuse bugs...